# Sending '@' special character with SendKeys to IE 11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, sendkeys, selenium-iedriver

I'm trying to send a special character to a textbox using the SendKeys method in Internet Explorer 11. I didn't have this problem while trying to send special characters in other browsers, but Internet Explorer is sending completely different characters when trying to send special characters.

Most of the specials characters do work (e.g. !#()$%&/) but the characters like @{}§ are not working, and instead of those characters, something like vbnm is written in the textbox. These letters represents the keys with which the special signs are created in combination with the key Alt Gr (e.g. Alt Gr + v = @, Alt Gr + b = {, Alt Gr + n = }, Alt Gr + m = §).

I tried using the Action object to send the keys with KeyDown method, but it was also unsuccessful, when trying to write a string with '@' in it (e.g. username@mail.com) the special sign is replaced with the letter 'v' (usernamevmail.com). I also tried to use the ASCII equivalent of the '@' sign but instead of the special character, I got the '64' text placed in the textbox.

```
private static string UserName
    {
        get { return Browser.GetSingleElement(Login.txtUserName).GetAttribute("value"); }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            var domElement = Browser.GetSingleElement(Login.txtUserName);
            Actions action = new Actions(Browser._driver);
            action.MoveToElement(domElement);
            action.Perform();
            domElement.Clear();
            action.KeyDown(Keys.LeftAlt);
            action.Perform();
            action.SendKeys(Keys.NumberPad6);
            action.SendKeys(Keys.NumberPad4);
            action.Perform();
            //action.MoveToElement(Browser.GetSingleElement(Login.txtUserName)).Click().KeyDown(Keys.LeftAlt).SendKeys("64").Perform();
            if (!Browser.SendKeys(Browser.GetSingleElement(Login.txtUserName), "@{}§~$%&()="))
                throw new Exception("Failed to send keys on Login.txtUserName DOM element.");
        }
    }
```

When sending "@{}§~$%&()=" string to the textbox I get this as an output.

[image: Username output when sending "@{}§~$%&()=" string to the textbox]

Comment: Have you tried using WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string text)?

Comment: @IamBatman just tried it now, it works, thank you for your comment

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad it helped.

Comment: Please could you describe the solution in more detail? I ran into a similar issue, and in my case what I see is the text is the exact same after calling `HtmlDecode` when I run your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
string a = "@{}§~$%&()=";
string b = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a);
```

Comment: Please could you describe the solution in more detail? I ran into a similar issue, and in my case what I see is `a == b` when I run your code.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Well thank you very much for the documentation, I was aware of that. I was interested in how this method should fit into this use case, where should I call it, etc.

Comment: How this supposed to help? Could you write the whole code?

Comment: This converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission into a decoded string and you get the same result as you send