# Error with SendKeys IEDriverServer selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I'm testing a web application and the login test works fine in Chrome but when I try to run the test in IExplorer I found a problem:

I sent the email to login with

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("xxxxxxxx")).SendKeys("test@test.com")
```

In Chrome when I run the test is writing `test@test.com` in the text box
But when I execute the test in IExplorer using the `IEDriverServer` the text box is filled with "`test2test.com`", is replacing the `@` key with a 2.

Comment: is it working for u? Strange issue, put email in string and then pass it

Comment: If you will get the answer please share answer with me. Nice Question I upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string email="test@test.com"
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("xxxxxxxx")).SendKeys(email)
```

Try this Answer

[Sending '@' special character with SendKeys to IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073463/sending-special-character-with-sendkeys-to-ie-11)

Comment: Hi, that Is what I do now, I don't understand why is not working and send and incorrect keywork

Comment: Strange for me too @FranciscoGonzalez. May be compiler reserve that word. But it works in chrome. May be it is IE specific

Comment: I hope my answer helps you, If yes please accept and upvote. I will try to find why it occurs

Comment: Yes is very strange behavior, I tried sending another "special" keyword like # and in the IE browser in writing a 3. Probably is an error in the driver

Comment: Yes try to update driver and see.Please update and see. otherwise use as I gave code

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073463/sending-special-character-with-sendkeys-to-ie-11

Comment: I'm using the latest driver, Is very strange. I tried to using WebUtility.HtmlDecode but don't works too:
string usernamefixed = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(username);

Comment: yes I update the driver to the last one but is not working. If I find the solution I'll share with you

Comment: The solution at the end was use a previous version of the driver. It seem to be that the new version have a Bug with the send keys function

Comment: I told you :) it means I am correct. Please upvote then :):):)

Comment: Some time latest driver make some trouble in working better to work with little older any way great work. Thats the reason +5